# Wrapping a mutable collection with a sequence

Tags: collections, f#, ienumerable

Occasionally, I want to return a mutable collection from a function as a sequence. Upcasting to `seq<_>` works, but the sequence could be downcasted and modified (not that it usually matters). My usual solution is to use a wrap-as-a-sequence function which has given rise to the following:

```
let wrap items = Seq.map id
let wrapDict dict = Seq.map ((|KeyValue|) >> snd)
```

Mostly for curiosity (and fun), what would be other ways of writing such functions, perhaps in a more idiomatic, concise, or performant way?

Comment: Why not wrap then mutable collection in a `ReadOnlyCollection<_>` before returning as a sequence, so downcasting then mutating is no longer an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Seq.readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340408.aspx) is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, perfect. Don't know why I never saw that before.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the function suggested by Stephan is probably the thing you're looking for.

However, there is one tricky thing - the `Seq.readonly` function (as well as `ReadOnlyCollection` or using `Seq.map`) wraps the sequence so that it cannot be mutated from the outside. However, it still has quite subtle behavior because the resulting sequence can be mutated by the object:

```
type Arr() = 
    let data = [| 1 .. 5 |]
    member x.ItemsSeq = Seq.readonly data
    member x.Mutate() = data.[0] <- 10

let a = Arr()
let s = a.ItemsSeq
printfn "%A" (s |> List.ofSeq) // [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
a.Mutate()
printfn "%A" (s |> List.ofSeq) // [10; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

I would think that this is quite unexpected behavior (in a mostly functional language).

So, if the internal collection is mutable, you may also consider creating a complete clone of the data that cannot be modified later and guarantees that the returned sequence will always give the same results. For example using `data |> Array.ofSeq |> Seq.readonly`

Comment: +1 good point, I've needed to use this approach in an implementation for generating lexicographical permutations, which used a single array with in-place modifications internally: http://projecteulerfun.blogspot.com/2010/06/problem-42-what-is-largest-n-digit.html